# CORS issue in nodemcu esp8266

Tags: cors, ionic3, webserver, esp8266, nodemcu

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.100.2:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Iam getting above error while trying to call put/post request in iot ESP8266 webserver.

Inorder to solve this , I tried adding below code. But nothing worked.

```
server.on("/", HTTP_OPTIONS, []() {
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    server.sendHeader("Allow", "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept");
});

server.on("/testPost", HTTP_POST, testCors);
server.on("/testPut", HTTP_PUT, testCors);
```

And inside the function

```
void testCors()
{
    Serial.print("HTTP Method: ");
    Serial.println(server.method());

    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    server.sendHeader("Allow", "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept");
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "");
}
```

**Thanks**

Comment: I never used this server before, but one thing that stands out to me is `server.on("/"`. To me this looks like you are only configuring the handler to handle the `/` endpoint. Have you checked if the function is called. If not, maybe you need to configure the path as some kind of wildcard, e.g. `/*`.

Comment: Yes thats right, but I didn't find a way to add a wildcard path in esp8266 webserver. But I am able to achive it inside `notFound`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the solution for the wildcard path that worked for me

```
void config_rest_server_routing()
{
    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
        server.send(200, "text/html",
                    "Welcome to the ESP8266 REST Web Server");
    });
    server.on("/leds", HTTP_GET, get_leds);
    server.on("/leds", HTTP_POST, testCors);
    server.on("/leds", HTTP_PUT, testCors);

    server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
}
void handleNotFound()
{
    if (server.method() == HTTP_OPTIONS)
    {
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10000");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,POST,GET,OPTIONS");
        server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        server.send(204);
    }
    else
    {
        server.send(404, "text/plain", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with adding the header to every request, as suggested by others, besides the annoying code duplication, is that you can't add it to `serveStatic()`. So I went into the source code and found `void enableCORS(bool enable)` Just add it before `begin()` and cors should now work for all routes.

```
server.enableCORS(true);
server.begin();
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just add this line before every response:

`server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`